# Usual approach doesn't work

Tags: integration

Show that $$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\cos^3(x)}{2 - \sin(2x)}=1.$$ 
Substituting $y= \pi/2 - x$ reduces the problem but does not help.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 \cos^3(x)}{2-\sin(2x)} dx$? Also, how about you show your reduction?

Comment: WolframAlpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B2%5Ccos%5E3(x)%7D%7B2+-+%5Csin(2x)%7D+integrate+from+0+to+pi%2F2 suggests that @Ian's understanding of the question is correct.

Comment: Substituing as indicstred gives cos**3(x)/(1 -sin(x)*cos(x). which isn't getting me anywhere. This is my problem I do not see how to proceed from here.

Comment: "Substituing as indicstred gives cos**3(x)/(1 -sin(x)*cos(x)" Hmmm, "substituting" should give an integral on y, where is it?

Comment: Inspired by Wolfram's solution (and the fact that it is known to work for any rational function of sine and cosine), you could alternatively try the half-angle substitution: $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2} dt$. Or, equivalently, $t=\tan(x/2)$ and rederive all that with trigonometry.

Comment: @Ian Yes this always works but in the specific case, there is a much simpler approach -- and one is bound to discover it as soon as one bothers to follow the hint...

Comment: @Callie12 Did you try carefully writing out the integral that you get after the substitution $y=\pi/2-x$ (limits and all)?

Comment: Sorry following substitution, the result stated is correct as x/y is a dummy variable.

Comment: I guess I am 'locked-in' to hoping the substitution may avoid use of the 't-method' but I could be wrong and need to slog it out. Ever wishful there would have been an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

$x\mapsto \frac{\pi}2 - x$

$$I=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^0 \frac{-2\sin^3 x}{2-\sin(\pi -2x)}dx =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{2\sin^3 x}{2-\sin(2x)}dx $$

So $$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\sin^3 x +\cos^3 x}{2-2\sin x \cos x}dx$$

Using $\sin^3 x +\cos^3 x=(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin^2 x -\sin x \cos x +\cos^2 x)=(\sin x+ \cos x)(1-\sin x \cos x)$ gives

$$I= \frac 12 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} (\sin x +\cos x)dx$$

Comment: That's the step I was totally missing. Great stuff. Thank you !